# How to access a Joomla 2.5 page without log in

Tags: joomla, ip, private

I have a website which direct the users to a Joomla 2.5 page, but I would like to keep my content (just an article) private and to be accessed just by authorized users (by IP) without their log in.

I have already searched a plugin, but I just found solutions with log in.

Can you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any plugins that support such a feature but one method (not the most efficient one) would be to edit the template **index.php** file like so:

```
<?php 

$allow = array("IP 1", "IP 2", "IP 3"); //allowed IPs

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow)) {

    // all your template code in here

}
else {
    //redirect if IP isn't allowed 
    header("Location: http://google.co.uk");
    exit();
}

?>
```

I haven't tested the code above so please bare in mind it may not be 100%

You may actually be interested in this Joomla Plugin.

http://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/auto-login-ip/packages

Just saw it whilst writing this answer. It automatically logs a user in from a specific or range of IP addresses. There is a free version, however it doesn't come with onsite or email support which shouldn't be a problem. Once installed, simply restrict your articles/content to registered users only.

Hope this helps